# AWS API Gateway as proxy for HTTP AUTH

Tags: api, amazon-web-services

I am dealing with some legacy applications and want to use Amazon AWS API Gateway to mitigate some of the drawbacks.

Application A, is able to call URLs with parameters, but does not support HTTP basic AUTH. Like this:

`https://example.com/api?param1=xxx&param2=yyy`

Application B is able to handle these calls and respond. BUT application B needs HTTP basic authentication.

**The question is now, can I use Amazon AWS API Gateway to mitigate this?**

The idea is to create an API of this style:

`http://amazon-aws-api.example.com/api?authcode=aaaa&param1=xxx&param2=yyy`

Then Amazon should check if the authcode is correct and then call the API from Application A with all remaining parameters while using some stored username+password. The result should just be passed along back to Application B.

I could also give username + password as a parameter, but I guess using a long authcode and storing the rather short password at Amazon is more secure. One could also use a changing authcode like the ones used in 2-factor authentications.

---

### Path to a solution:

I created the following AWS Lambda function based on the HTTPS template:

```
'use strict';

const https = require('https');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const req = https.get(event, (res) => {
        let body = '';
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', (chunk) => body += chunk);
        res.on('end', () => callback(null, body));
    });
    req.on('error', callback);
    req.end();
};
```

If I use the Test function and provide it with this event it works as expected:

```
{
    "hostname": "example.com",
    "path": "/api?param1=xxx&param2=yyy",
    "auth": "user:password"
}
```

I suppose the best way from here is to use the API gateway to provide an interface like: 
`https://amazon-aws-api.example.com/api?user=user&pass=pass&param1=xxx&param2=yyy`

Since the params of an HTTPs request are encrypted and they are not stored in Lambda, this method should be pretty secure.

The question is now, how to connect the API gateway to the Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the scenario mentioned with AWS API Gateway. However it won't be just a proxy integration, rather you need to have a Lambda function which will forward the request by doing the transformation.

If the credentials are fixed credentials to invoke the API, then you can use the environmental variables in Lambda to store them, encrypted by using AWS KMS Keys.

However if the credentials are sent for each user (e.g logged into the application from a web browser) the drawbacks of this approach is that you need to store username and password while also retrieving it. Its not encourage to store passwords even encrypted. If this is the case, its better to passthrough (Also doing the transformations) rather storing and retrieving in between.

Comment: This seems like an exception to the rule about not storing passwords, since it's not a user's password being stored... it's static credentials used to access the second API.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Your point is valid. I have improved the answer including both scenarios. Thanks!

Comment: @Ashan I tried it with Lambda and was partially successfull. Since I am new to this, I don't know how to connect API GW and Lambda accordingly. (See updated question)